# How to convert a string to a 24 byte array and pad it in Node.js

Tags: node.js, encryption, int, long-integer

We need to convert the following String "(secure random long number):(current time in ms)\n" into a 24 bytes, and then prepend this 24 bytes to a plaintext。How could I do this?

Comment: How long is `(secure random long number)`? What if it is more than 24 bytes?

Comment: (secure random long number) is a long number, should be 64 bits (8 bytes), right?

Comment: Please indicate what you want to use the 24 bytes for, I've assumed IV or nonce...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create a nonce or IV then you could simply hash the concatenation of the random number and current time in ms - e.g. using SHA-256 - and then take the 24 leftmost bytes.